# Do tensor equations hold with all indices up or down?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am starting with general relativity and the notation is making me suffer.

If we have, for example, the tensorial equation:
\begin{equation}
A^{\mu\nu} = K^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
Where $A$ and $K$ are two arbitrary rank 2 tensors, does this equation imply the following?
\begin{equation}
A_{\mu\nu} = K_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
Or even,\begin{equation}
A_\mu^\nu= K_\mu^\nu
\end{equation}
What we have done in the last two equations is raising or lowering indices with the metric. Is this true?

Comment: As a hint, try taking your first equation and subtracting $K^{\mu\nu}$ from both sides. If you multiply both sides the the metric factors needed to lower the indices on $A$ and $K$, what happens to the right hand side?

Comment: If you have two equal things, and multiply them by the same thing (raisng and lowering incides is a multiplication by a metric tensor), you will get two equal things

Comment: @Andrew the right hand side remains 0 and the left hand side becomes the difference of tensor but with the indices down multiplied by metric coefficients. Since metric coefficients are in general not 0, we conclude the equation with the indices down hold? That's my attempt.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator Since the multiplication in this case is a concraction it's not that clear to me, altough I think that what i wrote must be true.

Comment: $A_{\mu}^{\nu} = g_{\mu \alpha} A^{\nu \alpha}$ - it is a matrix multplication

Comment: Yes, a tensor contraction can be seen as a matrix multiplication when we have few indices. It is clearer though to see it in a matrix way, since it's known from highschool that AB=CB means A=C. Thanks!

Comment: Unless a tensor is symmetric, you can’t stack the indices. You have to indicate which is first and which is second.

Comment: @G.Smith  I have a question about that too. The indices have to be order respected because of the slot they are action on, right? I mean, $T_{\mu\nu}$ refears to the components of the tensor $T$ in the basis $e^\alpha$, $T=T_{\mu\nu}e^\mu  e^\nu$ (omitting tensor product) where $\mu $indexes the first slot and $\nu$ the second. In order words, the following tensors are different: $A=A^\mu_{\;\;\nu} e_\mu e^\nu$ and $A_\nu^{\;\;\mu}e^\nu e_\mu$. Am I right? Of course, if the tensor is symmetric then ordering doesnt matter.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator Answering in comments is actively discouraged on Physics SE.  We want questions to get posted answers so the system does not have a lot of apparently unanswered questions and because answers are easily found and used by other people.  You get more reputation points by providing an answer that is voted up and even more if the OP accepts it.

Comment: @NambuGotto Yes, that’s right.

Comment: @StephenG i know that, I thought that my claim is too short, to be considered as an answer

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator  No need to worry about the answer length.  Some questions have simple answers.  In general it helps attract votes from people if you provide a reasonably detailed answer (e.g. a short but relevant equation with the text), but unless you are just saying e.g. "yes" or "no" and nothing much else to help the OP, then short answers are fine.